# Singular Value Decomposition of 4x4 matrix in C

Tags: c, linear-algebra, svd, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I am ultimately trying to create a pseudoinverse function using svd methodology. I want to first create a SVD function that will give me the U, E and V matrices that I will later use in the formula below to get the pseudoinverse: [image]

I am not sure how to code these matrices. I understand how to do this by hand through eigen values and vectors but not sure how to translate that to c code.

I have already created functions for Transpose and matrix multiplication. Now its a matter of finding these 3 matrices.

Comment: Please show a [mre] of how your input data is represented, of how your result should be represented. Provide a useful sample input (ideally avoid using input reading, i.e. use hardcoded init values). Provide the expected result for that. Show the functions you have mentioned as already done and how they are used. Explain the math part, "by hand" is fine. That will either help you with making progress yourself or with finding help here.

Answer (score 0):

You can see a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035629/singular-value-decomposition-simple-code-in-c) asked question with a link to a source file.
They recommend to use openCV built-in function - you can find it [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/df/df7/classcv_1_1SVD.html) - the purpose is to use a ready function from the openCV library.